Call async function in .sheet or .fullScreenCover SwiftUI
Using RevenueCat and checking the users subscription status.
If Subscribed or not will determine the view shown in a fullScreenCover
Only as the call to check status is async I have to call with await and wrap in a Task{} which is not possible inside a fullScreenCover.
How to call a async function in a fullScreenCover
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $subscriptionIsExpanded){
                Task {
                if await StoreManager.isPremiumSubscriber() {
                          ActiveSubscription()
                        }
                   else{
                    PaywallView(displayCloseButton: true)
                }
            }
     }

Task{} gives error: Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Task<(), Never>' conform to 'View'

What you need show while isPremiumSubscriber loading?

Put the async part in .task body's are synchronous

You could try a different approach to call your async function
inside the .fullScreenCover or .sheet.
For example using a simple @State private var isDone: Bool? to display
the appropriate View as a result of your async task.
Example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var subscriptionIsExpanded = false
    @State private var isDone: Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Click me") {
                subscriptionIsExpanded = true
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
//        .sheet(isPresented: $subscriptionIsExpanded, onDismiss: { isDone = nil }) {
//            sheetView()
//        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $subscriptionIsExpanded) {
            sheetView()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func sheetView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Dismiss") {
                    isDone = nil
                    subscriptionIsExpanded = false
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            switch isDone {
                case true: Text("ActiveSubscription") // ActiveSubscription()
                case false: Text("PaywallView") // PaywallView(displayCloseButton: true)
                default: ProgressView()
            }
           Spacer()
        }
        .task {
            isDone = await isPremiumSubscriber()
            // isDone = await StoreManager.isPremiumSubscriber()
        }
    }
    
    // for testing, StoreManager.isPremiumSubscriber()
    func isPremiumSubscriber() async -> Bool {
        try! await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        return Int.random(in: 0...1) < 1
    }
    
}

